Rails Active Record query joins and merge get Ids
User -> Has many cats
Vaccinations -> has many cats
Cat -> belongs to vaccination
User::CatRecords is a namespaced ActiveRecord model -> belongs to cat

This is what I have tried so far
User::CatRecords.joins(cat: :vaccinations).merge(Cat.vaccinated)

What I am trying to achieve is get ids of all the cats in the query above.
How can I do it?

what is CatRecords, is it a namespaced ActiveRecord model? Is it a constant defined in the User model?

is it a namespaced ActiveRecord model and its belongs to cat

ActiveRecord class names should always be singular

@les nightingale thanks for that will update, do you know the answer to the problem ?

please show all the relationships between these four models, you are only showing part, maybe half, of them
